# Defining a block helper with Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to define a block helper that puts the text in the block into a `<a href=""></a>` tag. I used an example from http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html as a start but my code doesn't work. What do I have to change to get `<a href="http://www.example.com">test</a>` as the output of this block helper?

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(options) {
  var result = '<a href="http://www.example.com">' + options.fn(this) + '</a>';
  return Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <p>
        {{#link}}
        test
        {{/link}}
        </p>
      </script>

    </body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </html>
```

Comment: I get `test` and I'd like to get `<a href="http://www.example.com">test</a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a couple of details (EDITED):

- You just need to create a **new instance** of `Handlebars.SafeString` before returning it. Please check @muistooshort's [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Jaya/) with a working example of what you are trying to achieve.
- **Block helpers** are a little bit more complex and used when is needed to invoke a section of a template with a different context. If it is not your case, you could use the syntax for *regular* [Handlebars helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers). (I'll leave the following code here for future reference, although it's not relevant in this case)

Declare helper in **app.js**:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(value) {
  var result = '<a href="http://www.example.com">' + value + '</a>';
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

In **index.html** replace your current template with:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <p>
    {{link test}}
  </p>
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't help me. The 'test' is just an example. In my application there is a piece of HTML code (an image plus text) which should be embedded within a <a href> tag. How can I solve this?

Comment: @wintermeyer: I think the first bullet covers everything you need: http://jsfiddle.net/6Jaya/

Comment: @muistooshort that jsfiddle is great, I think you should add it as an answer here!

Comment: But your first "use `new`" bullet solves the problem so you're welcome to take it from here.