# Handlebar block helper doesn't work as it should

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I try to use the code from [Defining a block helper with Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769096/defining-a-block-helper-with-handlebars) to create a block helper. http://jsfiddle.net/6Jaya/ by @danii shows that it should work. But it doesn't. I get the following output:
[image: Screenshot]

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(options) {
    var result = '<a href="http://www.example.com">'
               + options.fn(this)
               + '</a>';
    console.log(result);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <p>
      {{#link}}
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
      {{/link}}
      </p>
    </script>

  </body>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example works for me

Comment: `console.log(arguments)` spits out an `[Object]`. What do you need to know exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use? Is there a specific reason for this?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(value) {
    var result = '<a href="http://www.example.com">'
               + value
               + '</a>';
    console.log(result);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```